# XmlSerializer ignores attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

XmlSerializer ignores class attributes.  I'm writing simple serializer, and I used `[Serializable]` and `[NonSerialized]` attributes, also I tried to use `[XmlRoot]` and `[XmlIgnore]`.  And I've noticed, although the field has the attribute `[NonSerialized]` it is serialized.

And it also ignores other attributes such as `[XmAtribute]`. Then I've noticed that it's even not necessary to use any attributes, and I can serialize class without these attributes, how can I ignore some fields?

My class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Route
{
    int busNumber;
    string busType, destination;
    DateTime departure, arrival;
    [NonSerialized]DateTime creationDate;
    ...
}
```

And I'm trying to serialize `List<Route>`

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\routes.xml");
    XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Route>));
    xmlSer.Serialize(stream, ((FileForm)ActiveMdiChild).routes);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Check this simple .Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ljPoyJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the [XmlIgnoreAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, properties that need to be serialized must be declared as `public`.

Usage as follows:

```
public class Route
{
    public int busNumber;
    public string busType, destination;
    public DateTime departure, arrival;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime creationDate;

    // how to ignore a property
    private int ignored;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Ignored { get { return ignored; } set { ignored = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ofk, as I wroute I tried to use Xml specific atributes, and I have get/set properties. It's just ignores any atribute.

Comment: Are you declaring all of your properties as `public`?  I just confirmed that this is needed in order for `XmlSerializer` to write them out.  The `XmlIgnore` attribute is added to `public` properties that you do not want serialized.

Comment: Just another question. What if I need this fields private, but with get/set methods? How can I write it?

Comment: Like this? `private int x; public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }`

Comment: Yes, like this.

Comment: Cuse I have some logic in getter property.

Comment: If the property has a public get/set then things will work as expected.  Is this your case?  If you have a complex example, it might be helpful to see some code.

Comment: Ok, it's just, when I use forexamlr `[XmlIgnore]public int x {get; set}` it all works as expected. Bus when I write `[XmlIgnore] private int x; public int X {get {return x;} set {x= value;}}` It serealize field and writes it to Xml file

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I believe that in your example the `XmlIgnore` attribute is in the incorrect place.

Comment: A, yeah, ofk. Thank you very much, You are realy helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the Serializer:

```
// Return an XmlSerializer used for overriding.
   public XmlSerializer CreateOverrider()
   {
      // Create the XmlAttributeOverrides and XmlAttributes objects.
      XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
      XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

      /* Setting XmlIgnore to false overrides the XmlIgnoreAttribute
         applied to the Comment field. Thus it will be serialized.*/
      attrs.XmlIgnore = false;
      xOver.Add(typeof(Group), "Comment", attrs);

      /* Use the XmlIgnore to instruct the XmlSerializer to ignore
         the GroupName instead. */
      attrs = new XmlAttributes();
      attrs.XmlIgnore = true;
      xOver.Add(typeof(Group), "GroupName", attrs);

      XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group), xOver);
      return xSer;
   }

   public void SerializeObject(string filename)
   {
      // Create an XmlSerializer instance.
      XmlSerializer xSer = CreateOverrider();

      // Create the object to serialize and set its properties.
      Group myGroup = new Group();
      myGroup.GroupName = ".NET";
      myGroup.Comment = "My Comment...";

      // Writing the file requires a TextWriter.
      TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

      // Serialize the object and close the TextWriter.
      xSer.Serialize(writer, myGroup);
      writer.Close();
   }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong attribute. Since you are using a XmlSerializer, you should use the XML specific attributes. Check this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx